# Get Control (Button) from parent in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, contentcontrol, visual-tree

I have a window with different items and different views for each type.
I would like to access the button in the window (parent) from my code behind from the content control.

**OutputConfigView**:

```
                    <ContentControl Margin="5">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedOutputRendererTyp}" Value="{x:Type outTypes:XmlBarcodeRenderer}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OutputRendererView}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedOutputRendererTyp}" Value="{x:Type outTypes:CsvBarcodeRenderer}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CsvOutputRendererView}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>                          
                      .
                      .

        <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Click="WindowClose"
                Content="Ok"
                Margin="0 0 0 -5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Button>
```

**OutputRendererView.xaml.cs**:

```
 public partial class OutputRendererView : UserControl
{
    public OutputRendererView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         var parentWindow = (OutputRendererView)this.Parent;
         var button = (Button)parentWindow.FindName("CloseButton");
    }
```

In this case the parentWindow is null.

**How can I access the button of the calling window from the code behind of my control ?**

Answer (score 0):

To access the button inside the user control, you must first find the `usercontrol` and then the `button` inside it.

```
var button = (Button)((UserControl)parentWindow.FindName("userControlName")).FindName("CloseButton");
```

Comment: The button is in the parentview (OutputConfigView) and i dont get the parent.